# AS400: explore structure via Java/SQL

Tags: java, database

I am trying to explore the internal structure of an AS400 via Java and I would like to obtain the list of all databases and, for each of them, the list of all tables. 
In MySQL I would use "show databases" and, after "use mydb", I would type "show tables".

I tried "LIST DATABASE DIRECTORY" and "LIST DATABASES", as well as "LIST TABLES", but it does not work: "[SQL0104] Token LIST non valido. Token validi: ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer obtained in a specialized forum: http://www.code400.com/forum/showthread.php/12794-AS400-explore-structure-via-Java-SQL

*"*Meta data for the DB2 for i Database can be accessed via SQL over the catalog views in the QSYS2 schema. All catalog views start with SYS. The SCHEMA (library) information is found in SYSSCHEMAS. The table information is found in SYSTABLES

*As an aside (you seem not to be familar with the IBM i terms):**

*1. AS/400 is an old term: The current name of the machine and operating system is IBM i
2. The database name is: DB2 for i and there is only a single database on an IBM i
3. All (database) object are stored in schemas (or libraries)
4. For IBM i applications usually tables in multiple schemas/libraries are accessed using library lists.*"*